# Output linearmodels regression summary as latex

Tags: python, statistics, latex, statsmodels, linearmodels

How can I print out the summary table of a fitted linearmodels object as latex?

For example, how can I print `res` as latex code?

```py
# Libraries
import pandas as pd
from linearmodels.panel import PanelOLS
from linearmodels.datasets import wage_panel

# Load silly data
df = wage_panel.load()

# Set indexes
df = df.set_index(['nr','year'])

# Fit silly model
mod = PanelOLS(dependent=df['lwage'], exog=df[['hours','married','educ']], time_effects=True)
res = mod.fit()

# Print results
print(res)
                          PanelOLS Estimation Summary                           
================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                  lwage   R-squared:                        0.0933
Estimator:                   PanelOLS   R-squared (Between):              0.7056
No. Observations:                4360   R-squared (Within):               0.0373
Date:                Thu, Nov 04 2021   R-squared (Overall):              0.6764
Time:                        23:48:11   Log-likelihood                   -3055.6
Cov. Estimator:            Unadjusted                                           
                                        F-statistic:                      149.14
Entities:                         545   P-value                           0.0000
Avg Obs:                       8.0000   Distribution:                  F(3,4349)
Min Obs:                       8.0000                                           
Max Obs:                       8.0000   F-statistic (robust):             149.14
                                        P-value                           0.0000
Time periods:                       8   Distribution:                  F(3,4349)
Avg Obs:                       545.00                                           
Min Obs:                       545.00                                           
Max Obs:                       545.00                                           
                                                                                
                             Parameter Estimates                              
==============================================================================
            Parameter  Std. Err.     T-stat    P-value    Lower CI    Upper CI
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
hours      -7.571e-05  1.357e-05    -5.5805     0.0000     -0.0001  -4.911e-05
married        0.1573     0.0157     10.017     0.0000      0.1265      0.1881
educ           0.0765     0.0042     18.048     0.0000      0.0682      0.0848
==============================================================================

F-test for Poolability: 41.795
P-value: 0.0000
Distribution: F(7,4349)

Included effects: Time
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the `summary` attribute. Just note that you'll have to use the `booktabs` package in Latex.

```py
print(res.summary.as_latex())
```

Which prints:

> \begin{center} \begin{tabular}{lclc} \toprule \textbf{Dep. Variable:}
> &       lwage        & \textbf{  R-squared:         }   &      0.0933
> \ \textbf{Estimator:}        &      PanelOLS      & \textbf{
> R-squared (Between):}  &      0.7056      \ \textbf{No.
> Observations:} &        4360        & \textbf{  R-squared (Within):}
> &      0.0373      \ \textbf{Date:}             &  Thu, Nov 04 2021
> & \textbf{  R-squared (Overall):}  &      0.6764      \
> \textbf{Time:}             &      23:50:24      & \textbf{
> Log-likelihood     }   &     -3055.6      \ \textbf{Cov. Estimator:}
> &     Unadjusted     & \textbf{                     }   &
> \ \textbf{}                  &                    & \textbf{
> F-statistic:       }   &      149.14      \ \textbf{Entities:}
> &        545         & \textbf{  P-value            }   &      0.0000
> \ \textbf{Avg Obs:}          &       8.0000       & \textbf{
> Distribution:      }   &    F(3,4349)     \ \textbf{Min Obs:}
> &       8.0000       & \textbf{                     }   &
> \ \textbf{Max Obs:}          &       8.0000       & \textbf{
> F-statistic (robust):} &      149.14      \ \textbf{}
> &                    & \textbf{  P-value            }   &      0.0000
> \ \textbf{Time periods:}     &         8          & \textbf{
> Distribution:      }   &    F(3,4349)     \ \textbf{Avg Obs:}
> &       545.00       & \textbf{                     }   &
> \ \textbf{Min Obs:}          &       545.00       & \textbf{
> }   &                  \ \textbf{Max Obs:}          &       545.00
> & \textbf{                     }   &                  \ \textbf{}
> &                    & \textbf{                     }   &
> \ \bottomrule \end{tabular} \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
> & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Std. Err.} & \textbf{T-stat} & \textbf{P-value} & \textbf{Lower CI} & \textbf{Upper
> CI}  \ \midrule \textbf{hours}   &     -7.571e-05     &     1.357e-05
> &     -5.5805     &      0.0000      &      -0.0001      &
> -4.911e-05     \ \textbf{married} &       0.1573       &       0.0157       &      10.017     &      0.0000      &       0.1265      &
> 0.1881       \ \textbf{educ}    &       0.0765       &       0.0042       &      18.048     &      0.0000      &       0.0682      &
> 0.0848       \ \bottomrule \end{tabular} %\caption{PanelOLS Estimation Summary} \end{center}
>
> F-test for Poolability: 41.795 \newline  P-value: 0.0000 \newline
> Distribution: F(7,4349) \newline   \newline  Included effects: Time